# How to remove the cell separation line from a table, while preserving the last cell's horizontal line with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Given a table like this:

```css
table {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-spacing: 75px 0px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

td {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: unset;">
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet. Sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Augue eget arcu dictum varius duis. Volutpat
        est velit egestas dui. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum </td>
      <td>Neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in. Sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis. Elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat. Facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. In arcu cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras. Ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra. Sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula.</td>
      <td>Nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent. Nec dui nunc mattis enim ut.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem ipsum dolor sit. Neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in. Sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis. Elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant. Dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat. Facilisi cras fermentum
        odio eu feugiat. In arcu cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras. Ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra. Sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula.</td>
      <td>Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio. Dolor sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim. Sit amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eget arcu dictum varius duis at. Diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque.</td>
      <td> Dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat. Facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I replace for a space the separator line between each row, leaving the last buttom line so the table is complete, something like this:

[image]

So far I tried to add to the style this:

```
  border-bottom: none;
```

And

```
td:last-child{
      border-bottom: 0px solid black;

}
```

However, the problem is that the above removes the last line in the table:

[image]

**What is the correct way of replacing the horizontal lines that separate each row in the table, while preserving the last line, so the table looks "closed"?**

Comment: hey you mean to say that your code removes the last line?

Comment: That's correct @Aahad, I would like to preserve only the last line, while removing the other lines. I also tried this `tr:last-child td:last-child{
    border:none;
}
` However it is still not working

Comment: hey  check the code I have added for you I hope it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this in your css. Basically what it does it check for if tr is not a last child than it will remove the border of its td child

```
tr:not(:last-child) td {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: I did not know you could do things like this `tr:not(:last-child)`

Comment: yup, you can do that. Also, you can use it in many other scenarios for example div:not(.classname). Read more about not class here
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and I hope this will help you with it!

```css
 table {
                padding: 10px;
                border: 0px solid black;
                border-radius: 10px;
                border-spacing: 75px 0px;
                padding-left: 50px;
              }
              
              p {
                height: 20px;
                padding: 15px;
                width: 50%;
                border-top: none;
              }
```

```html
    <DOCTYPE! html>
        <html>
        <head>
        
           
        </head>
        
        <body>
           
              <table border="1" class="dataframe">
                <thead>
                  <tr style="text-align: unset;">
                    <th>Col 1</th>
                    <th>Col 2</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                    <p>i guess this will work fine for you</p>
                    
                    <p>ss</p>
                    <p>ss</p>
                    <p>ss</p>
                    <p>ss</p>
                    <p>ss</p>
                <p>ss</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>hello does this works fine </p>
                    <p>ss</p>
                    
                    <p>ss</p>
                    <p>ss</p>
                    <p>ss</p>
                    <p>ss</p>
                    <p>ss</p>
                </td>  
               
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
        </body>
        </html>
```

```
thanks
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the CSS style does not seem to work https://jsfiddle.net/ahmqyobd/

Comment: Thanks, in the last cell only, so the table is "closed" in the bottom

Comment: you have to edit your code also not only css

Comment: Is there any way of doing this only with the CSS? Thanks for the help

Comment: does this help you?@aywoki

Comment: Its a good solution, however, I can only change the CSS :(

Comment: Yes its working, however, as I am receiving these tables automaticaly I cant change the style of them

Comment: add all  <p> tag of both tables in two different <div> as <div class="one"> for first table and <div class="two"> for second table and style them